# can i paint my bathtub wall?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, paint, bathtub, waterproofing

One of our bath walls is green Sheetrock with a white semi gloss paint finish.
As you can see on the pictures attached, the paint has started to bubble and strip.

[image]
[image: paint stripping @ sealer]
[image]

What can we do now?

1. shall/can we tile?
2. can we keep a painted wall (our aesthetic preference) but using another primer and an exterior type paint? in that case what shall we use?
3. are there any cement layers that could be added to the wall and that would allow us to have a white finish?

Wall behind tile and paint.
[image]
[image]

Found construction picture (shows what is behind the sheetrock).

We really cannot tell from photos if they used vapor barrier or not...

[image]

Comment: No wet seal in a shower even if it is cement sheet is a really bad idea! And Plaster... Really.. You could put laminex in but get it custom made to size for a gloss look

Comment: What is mounted in the electrical box?  I sure hope it is a shower rated fixture. It is way to close to the water source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any Sheetrock, including green moisture resistant, is not intended for use in showers or any environment with repeated direct water contact. You can paint it , but the results will be the same, FAILURE !  Do not attempt to put tile on Drywall either. There are some new high tech backings or you can use good old fashion concrete board or hardi-backer for tiles.  If you want a water proof glossy finish, you may have to consider a fiberglass surround kit, which can be installed over green sheetrock or preferably directly over studs with a vapor barrier.

Comment: Because the first photo wasn't rotated, I didn't realize at first that the painted wall was at tub-level where it would be exposed to direct water contact, so I voted to delete my answer.  I agree completely with this answer.  You can't have drywall in a shower below the shower head level.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses,  unfortunately our contractor used green sheetrock for the side that he painted white and durock for the side of the bathtub (up to a certain level). See fourth picture attached on the question. What do you suggest we do now?  Calling this contractor and asking him to redo this is not an option. <BR> Also, what kits are these fiberglass you are mentioning? do you know any particular brand for this kit?

Comment: Looking at the forth pic, I see a window. that would preclude using a full surround kit.  What type of tiles are those black squares?  I didn't see any vapor barrier behind the rock, is it there?  You may have to use tile board on the ends. This could be glued to the existing rock. Not the best solution, but the cheapest. I'd pull the rock, replace with concrete board and put up tile.  The little detail on the left side of the tub also adds a degree of difficulty to using a kit..

Comment: Hi Shirlock, we found another construction photo, from there we cannot tell if they used vapor barrier between the insulation and the rock... (I did not see any vapor roll around the house, so I guess they did not either). We are looking for solutions to avoid demolishing the whole bathroom. And we are wondering if there are any cement layers that can be applied on the fixture wall to waterproof it. Just saw that Benjamin moore has a bath and spa paint and was wondering if that could work.

Comment: Just found the below: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTJcIfzu7Bs Do you think this solution could work (for the wall that has the fixtures?)

Comment: I'm skeptical of the product in the youtube link for showers. 1) I don't trust the "waterproof" membrane. 2) the actual material is porous and needs a sealer. I fear mold and mildew growth. 3) Unless the surface is meticulously polished, it will be difficult to clean. Still think more tile is the best approach. If you really want a solid white plane, perhaps you can source a sheet of material like that used in tub surrounds.

Comment: I agree with bcworkz.  I don't buy the concept. You still have sheetrock ends in places that can hold water and it will wick up eventually, swell and destroy the rock. It really is not that difficult to take it off and do it right.

Comment: Thank you shirlock.  Our problem comes when trying to find a new contractor that could do this properly with minimal downtime to the bathroom.  I guess this could take about 3 days of work?

Comment: The actual labor time should only be around 8 to 12 hours, but the process could take a couple of days.  Chat with some folks at the local Lowes, HD, or bathroom tile supplier and ask them for a referral to a trusted contractor that they have experience with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to remove the sheetrock from around the tub and put backer board and tile on it. I don't see any way that sheetrock around a shower like that is going to last.

How is it you have construction photos? Whas it done by somebody you know? Maybe you can ask them "What were you thinking?"